# How to use IN operator within the table data when using Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one table which contains columns and data as below:

```
KEY(string)  DAY(string)
1            (1,2,3,4)
2            (2,3,4,5)
```

I would like to select the row which has 1 inside the `day` column. Therefore, I construct the following statement:

```
select * from test where 1 in day;
```

I got an error after running this:

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.
```

But if I write the statement as below:

```
select * from test where 1 in (1,2,3,4,5);
```

It works fine.

How can I use `IN` operator within the list stored in the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be `LIKE`:

```
select * from test
where day like '%1%'
```

It presumes that there aren't 10 or 11 or 31 days in that column, otherwise `LIKE` will find all of them, which is probably not what you wanted. In that case, see if `%,1,%` helps (which is a simple "solution").

But, if days are "7 days in a week", the initial statement should be OK.

---

If you have to compare today's day number with the `DAY` values, then see if this helps: you don't have to use Julian dates, `MOD` function, whatever you planned to do as Oracle offers `TO_CHAR`'s `D` format mask which returns day number. For example, today is Thursday, 10th of October 2019. Function returns

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> select sysdate today,
  2         to_char(sysdate, 'd') todays_number
  3  from dual;

TODAY      T
---------- -
10.10.2019 4
```

so you can use it in `like`:

```
SQL> with test (key, day) as
  2    (select 1, '1,2,3,4' from dual union all
  3     select 2, '2,3,4,5' from dual
  4    )
  5  select key,
  6         day,
  7         to_char(sysdate, 'd') todays_number
  8  from test
  9  where day like '%' || to_char(sysdate, 'd') || '%';

       KEY DAY     T
---------- ------- -
         1 1,2,3,4 4
         2 2,3,4,5 4

SQL>
```

If today was, for example, Friday 25th of October 2019, then you'd have

```
SQL> with test (key, day) as
  2    (select 1, '1,2,3,4' from dual union all
  3     select 2, '2,3,4,5' from dual
  4    )
  5  select key,
  6         day,
  7         to_char(date '2019-10-25', 'd') todays_number
  8  from test
  9  where day like '%' || to_char(date '2019-10-25', 'd') || '%';

       KEY DAY     T
---------- ------- -
         2 2,3,4,5 5

SQL>
```

Basically, I think that it might work.

Comment: Yep. The days are "7 days in a week", can you explain why does the `IN` operator cannot work in this case?

Comment: And this is just a simplified example. In my code, I have to convert the system date to the actual `number of the day in a week`. Therefore, I'm not sure whether I can do something like:  `where day like "%MOD(TO_CHAR(lastdate, 'J'), 7) + 1)%"`

Answer (score 0):

`(1,2,3,4)` is not a list or numbers it is a string with the characters `'('`, `'1'`, `','`, `'2'`, `','`, `'3'`, `','`, `'4'` and `')'`.

Your query is effectively:

```
SELECT *
FROM   DUAL
WHERE  1 IN ( '(a,b,c,d)' )
```

Where the `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` character just happen to have been replaced with numeric characters.

You get the error because the data-types do not match as `1` is a number and `days` is a string (it is not a list of numbers).

Instead you can use:

```sql
select *
from   test
where  REPLACE( REPLACE( days, '(', ',' ), ')', ',' ) LIKE '%,' || 1 || ',%';
```

Alternatively, you could store the "list" as an actual collection/nested table (rather than a delimited string):

```sql
CREATE TYPE int_list IS TABLE OF INT;

CREATE TABLE test ( key NUMBER, days int_list )
  NESTED TABLE days STORE AS test__days;

INSERT INTO test ( key, days ) VALUES ( 1, int_list( 1, 2, 3, 4 ) );
INSERT INTO test ( key, days ) VALUES ( 2, int_list( 2, 3, 4, 5 ) );
```

Then you can use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   test
WHERE  1 MEMBER OF days
```